# TensorFlow, Dataset API and flat_map operation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm having difficulties working with `tf.contrib.data.Dataset` API and wondered if some of you could help. I wanted to transform the entire `skip-gram` pre-processing of word2vec into this paradigm to play with the API a little bit, it involves the following operations:

1. Sequence of tokens are loaded dynamically (to avoid loading all dataset in memory at a time), say we then start with a `Stream` (to be understood as Scala's way, all data is not in memory but loaded when access is needed) of sequence of tokens: `seq_tokens`.
2. From any of these `seq_tokens` we extract skip-grams with a python function that returns a list of tuples `(token, context)`.
3. Select for features the column of `token`s and for label the column of `context`s.

In pseudo-code to make it clearer it would look like above. We should be taking advantage of the framework parallelism system not to load by ourselves the data, so I would do something like first load in memory only the indices of sequences, then load sequences (inside a `map`, hence if not all lines are processed synchronously, data is loaded asynchronously and there's no OOM to fear), and apply a function on those sequences of tokens that would create a varying number of skip-grams that needs to be flattened. In this end, I would formally end up with `data` being of shape `(#lines=number of skip-grams generated, #columns=2)`.

```
data = range(1:N)
  .map(i => load(i): Seq[String]) // load: Int -> Seq[String] loads dynamically a sequence of tokens (sequences have varying length)
  .flat_map(s => skip_gram(s)) // skip_gram: Seq[String] -> Seq[(String, String)] with output length
features = data[0] // features
lables = data[1] // labels
```

I've tried naively to do so with `Dataset`'s API but I'm stuck, I can do something like:

```
iterator = (
  tf.contrib.data.Dataset.range(N)
  .map(lambda i: tf.py_func(load_data, [i], [tf.int32, tf.int32])) // (1)
  .flat_map(?) // (2)
  .make_one_shot_iterator()
)
```

(1) TensorFlow's not happy here because sequences loaded have differents lengths...

(2) Haven't managed yet to do the skip-gram part... I actually just want to call a python function that computes a sequence (of variable size) of skip-grams and flatten it so that if the return type is a matrix, then each line should be understood as a new line of the output `Dataset`.

Thanks a lot if anyone has any idea, and don't hesitate if I forgot to mention useful precisions...

Comment: I'm new to Dataset API as well. Maybe the "Batching tensors with padding" section on the official guide "Using the Dataset API for TensorFlow Input Pipelines" can help you? https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/programmers_guide/datasets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just implementing the same thing; here's how I solved it:

```
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filename)

if mode == ModeKeys.TRAIN:
  dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=batch_size * 100)

dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda line: string_to_skip_gram(line))

dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

In my dataset, I treat every line as standalone, so I'm not worrying about contexts that span multiple lines.

I therefore flat map each line through a function `string_to_skip_gram` that returns a `Dataset` of a length that depends on the number of tokens in the line.

`string_to_skip_gram` turns the line into a series of tokens, represented by IDs (using the method `tokenize_str`) using `tf.py_func`:

```
def string_to_skip_gram(line):
  def handle_line(line):
    token_ids = tokenize_str(line)

    (features, labels) = skip_gram(token_ids)

    return np.array([features, labels], dtype=np.int64)

  res = tf.py_func(handle_line, [line], tf.int64)

  features = res[0]
  labels = res[1]

  return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
```

Finally, `skip_gram` returns a list of all possible context words and target words:

```
def skip_gram(token_ids):
  skip_window = 1

  features = []
  labels = []

  context_range = [i for i in range(-skip_window, skip_window + 1) if i != 0]

  for word_index in range(skip_window, len(token_ids) - skip_window):
    for context_word_offset in context_range:
      features.append(token_ids[word_index])
      labels.append(token_ids[word_index + context_word_offset])

  return features, labels
```

Note that I'm not sampling the context words here; just using all of them.

Comment: Works like a charm and is way more elegant than what I had done before, thanks for sharing.